# Finding integer pairs having same functional values

Tags: number-theory

We have a curve $$z=cxy-x^2y-xy^2,$$ where $c$ is some positive integer constant. How to find the set of integer pairs $(x,y)$ such that they give the same nonzero integral value of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $u:=x, v:=y, w:=(c-x-y)$. This means you want to find 3 integers whose sum is $c$ and whose produdct is $z$:

$$u+v+w=c$$

$$uvw = z$$

Since this is totally symmetric in $u,v,w$, you can get additional solutions by exchanging $u,v$ and $w$:
$$u:=x, v:=c-x-y$$ and
$$u:=c-x-y, v:=y.$$

This is another way to get what Nicolas FRANCOIS wrote above.

It may or may not be easier to tackle the question if there are more solutions to this equaion than simple permutation (it may even be the point from which you are coming). If we change the view to complex numbers, each $u$ that is chosen will result in a quadratic equation for $v,w$ with a single solution (up to exchanging $v$ and $w$). I don't see why, for some $c$ and $z$, chosing another integer as $u$ might not result in integer $v,w$.

Added: An example would be $z=36, c=13$, which allows the essentially different solution (1,6,6) and (2,2,9). This also means that the "only if" part of Nicolas FRANCOIS' comment is not correct.

Further addition: I can't find a better method at the moment to find all solutions as to have $x=u$ run through all the divsiors of $z$, and solve the quadratic equation in each case, checking if an integer $v,w$ is produced.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer.

Since $cxy-x^2y-xy^2 =  x y (c - x - y)$, every pair $(x,y)$ with $x+y=c$ gives $z=0$.

Comment: More generally : $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ gives the same $z$ if and only if $xy=x'y'$ (so that they belong to the same quadratic hyperbola of the plane $(Oxy)$) and $x+y=x'+y'$ (so that they belong to the same straight line parallel to the line $y=-x$ of the plane).

Comment: This argument is incorrect. Consider z=36, c=13. Then (2,2) and (1,6) are pairs which satisfy the above equation. Even though their product and sum are not the same.